# How to train and predict a model using Random Forest?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, random-forest

How can we predict a model using `random forest`? I want to train a model and finally predict a truth value using a `random forest model in Python` of the [three column dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Ajk8jGD1OxSEl2cnF6TC1lUXM) (click the link to download the full `CSV`-dataset formatted as in the following

```
t_stamp,X,Y
0.000543,0,10
0.000575,0,10
0.041324,1,10
0.041331,2,10
0.041336,3,10
0.04134,4,10
0.041345,5,10
0.04135,6,10
0.041354,7,10
```

I wanted to predict the current value of `Y` (the true value) using the last (for example: 5, 10, 100, 300, 1000, ..etc) data points of `X` using `random forest model` of `sklearn` in `Python`. Meaning taking `[0,0,1,2,3]` of `X` column as an input for the first window - i want to predict the 5th row value of `Y` trained on the previous values of `Y`. Similarly, using a simple `rolling OLS regression model`, we can do it as in the following but I wanted to do it using `random forest model`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data_pred.csv')
model = pd.stats.ols.MovingOLS(y=df.Y, x=df[['X']], 
                               window_type='rolling', window=5, intercept=True)
```

I have solved this problem with `random forest`, which yields `df`:

```
t_stamp     X    Y     X_t1    X_t2     X_t3    X_t4    X_t5
0.000543    0   10      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
0.000575    0   10      0.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
0.041324    1   10      0.0     0.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
0.041331    2   10      1.0     0.0     0.0     NaN     NaN
0.041336    3   10      2.0     1.0     0.0     0.0     NaN
0.041340    4   10      3.0     2.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
0.041345    5   10      4.0     3.0     2.0     1.0     0.0
0.041350    6   10      5.0     4.0     3.0     2.0     1.0
0.041354    7   10      6.0     5.0     4.0     3.0     2.0
 .........................................................   
[ 10.  10.  10.  10. .................................]
MSE: 1.3273548431
```

This seems to work fine for ranges 5, 10, 15, 20, 22. However, it doesn't seem to work fine for ranges greater than 23 (it prints `MSE: 0.0`) and this is because, as you can see from the [dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Iv8dfU4fTUY2ltNGVkMG05V00) the values of `Y` are fixed (10) from row 1 - 23 and then changes to another value (20, and so on) from row 24. How can we train and predict a model of such cases based on the last data points?

Comment: I get low values for ranges greater than 10. But it isn't 0. The MSE should decrease, it's a measure of the error in prediction. So what's the problem?

Comment: I think the reason why we are getting a small `MSE` is that probably becase the model is memorizing the single value of `Y` (when the value of `Y` remains unchanged (with a constant value) - for example from row 1 to row 23).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems with the existing code, when calling `dropna`, you truncate `X` but not `y`. You also train and test on the same data.

Fixing this will give non-zero MSE.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/shivadeviah/Desktop/estimated_pred.csv')

df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'X_%d'%i : df['X'].shift(i) for i in range(25)})
df1['Y'] = df['Y']
df1 = df1.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
df1.dropna(inplace=True)

X = df1.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = df1.iloc[:, -1].values

x = int(len(X) * 0.66)

X_train = X[:x]
X_test = X[x:]
y_train = y[:x]
y_test = y[x:]

reg = RandomForestRegressor(criterion='mse')
reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

modelPred = reg.predict(X_test)

print(modelPred)
print("Number of predictions:",len(modelPred))

meanSquaredError = mean_squared_error(y_test, modelPred)

print("MSE:", meanSquaredError)
print(df1.size)
df2 = df1.iloc[x:, :].copy()


df2['pred'] = modelPred

df2.head()
```

Output:

```
[ 267.7     258.26608241  265.07037249 ...,  267.27370169  256.7     272.2 ]
Number of predictions: 87891
MSE: 1954.9271256
6721026

        X_0       pred
170625  48  267.700000
170626  66  258.266082
170627  184 265.070372
170628  259 294.700000
170629  271 281.966667
```

Comment: @Mahsolid Well, that's because you're training and testing on the same data!

Comment: I did buddy but still the value is way too low. Can we put the predicted value in the last column (meaning `t_stamp, X, Y, Predicted`? I want to see if that is really the case

Comment: If you have checked your email, like i mentioned in the email I want to compare the MSE of the two methods buddy? but the MSE i am getting from `random forest` is way too low. One side question, you have `df` and `df1` - i can not see where you used `df1`?

Comment: @Mahsolid Forget OLS for now. Let's look at this. I've made a couple of changes to my code. It seems the MSE has shot up now. Have also shown the predictions side by side.

Comment: This is so much better even though the MSE is very high now buddy and thank you. Does `x = int(len(X) * 0.66)` mean `66%`? Is there any way to divide the data into train and test in OLS as well so that we can compare?

Comment: @Mahsolid My pandas version does not have pd.stats.ols :(

Comment: Yes, it means 66% training, 33% testing. I have not used OLS, so I don't know. My advice would be to just pass X and y and see what you get.

Comment: @Mahsolid I don't have Anaconda and I'm not looking to install it. I hope this is enough to get you started on your own. Best of luck, and sorry I couldn't help more. :)

Comment: @Mahsolid This post does answer the question in your OP (this question has nothing to do with OLS), so do consider accepting. ;P If not, that's alright.

Comment: Sure and done :-) I still have to compare the MSE values but you deserve it for your time and help buddy!

Comment: @Mahsolid Thanks again my friend. I'm only 40 away from 10k now!

Comment: I will ask another question soon and give you those 40's too :D you are welcome buddy!

Comment: @Mahsolid I'll be happy to answer, as long as I don't have to install conda. Cheers!

Comment: I would appreciate if you could have a look at this buddy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45374281/how-to-plot-a-predicted-value-and-truth-value-in-the-same-graph-using-python